# Testing Service in Grails produces 'org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<An[a]nymous> but was:<An[o]nymous>' error

Tags: grails, service, integration-testing

I'm working my way through 'Grails in Action' and I'm running into an issue when trying to write an Integration test for one of my services.

I realize that I'm using Grails 2.0.3 whereas the book was written with Grails 1.x.x in mind.

Here is my Service:

```
package qotd
```

class QuoteService {

```
boolean transactional = true

def getRandomQuote(){

    def allQuotes = Quote.list()
    def randomQuote

    if(allQuotes.size() > 0){
        def randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(allQuotes.size())
        randomQuote = allQuotes[randomIndex]
    }
    else{
        randomQuote = getStaticQuote()
    }
    return randomQuote

}

def getStaticQuote(){
    return new Quote(author: "Anonymous",
    content: "Real Programmers Don't eat quiche")
}
```

}

And below is my Integration Test, located in '/test/integration/qotd/'

```
package qotd
```

import static org.junit.Assert.*

import org.junit.*

class QuoteServiceIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {

```
def quoteService

@Before
void setUp() {
}

@After
void tearDown() {
}

@Test
void testStaticQuote() {
    def staticQuote = quoteService.getStaticQuote()
    assertNotNull quoteService
    assertEquals "Ananymous",staticQuote.author
    assertEquals "Real Programmers Don't Eat Quiche",staticQuote.content

}
```

}

Just in case it may be relevant, here is the Quote class that I'm testing the contents of above:

package qotd

class Quote {

```
String content
String author
Date created = new Date()

static constraints = {

    author(blank:false)
    content(maxSize:1000,blank:false)

}
```

}

When I run my test, using 'test-app -integration' I get the following:

---

Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
Failure:  testStaticQuote(qotd.QuoteServiceIntegrationTests)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: An[a]nymous but was:An[o]nymous
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:125)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at qotd.QuoteServiceIntegrationTests.testStaticQuote(QuoteServiceIntegrationTests.groovy:24)

---

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

you spelled "Anonymous" incorrectly on this line

`assertEquals "Ananymous",staticQuote.author`

Comment: You're entirely correct, and here I was thinking that it was an error! Thank you :)